# Given length L find the shortest string formed only of as & bs >= L such that adding some character (Either a or b) doesn't produce a new palindrome

Tags: string, algorithm, palindrome

Given length L find the shortest string >= L formed only of as & bs  such that adding some character (Either a or b) doesn't produce a new palindrome substring (never seen before palindrome)

For example for L = 1
there is the string aabbaba, adding "a" to it to result in aabbabaa will only produce the palindromes "a" and "aa" which were seen before at the 1st and 2nd character positions,
but for example the string aabab doesn't work because adding "b" or "a" will produce the new palindromes "bb" and "ababa" respectively

I'm not even sure aabbaba is the optimal solution for L = 1.
Any ideas on an algorithm to solve this fast?

Comment: For L=1, wouldn't "a" be the shortest string? One could just append "b". I think it gets more complicated starting at L=2.

Comment: Are you sure about "aabbaba" even working?  If you add "b", don't you get the new substring "babab", which hasn't been seen yet?  Or do you mean that you only have to be able to add *one* of the two letters (either "a" or "b") and not produce anything new?

Comment: aabbaba  is not palindromic or do you include acoustic palindromes ?

Comment: @SpecialSauce, You're right, I guess this is the the answer for L = [2, 7], I edited the question

Comment: @DSM, adding only one of the two characters

Comment: @Nassim The string itself doesn't have to be palindromic

Comment: @SpecialSauce My bad, actually "a" is not valid for L = 1 because b itself is a new palindrome, So my answer is still valid for L = [1, 7] and I edited the question back :D

Comment: Good point, I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are my results so far:

- `L=1-7`: "aabbaba" -> "aabbabaa" (or the mirror, confirming your result)
- `L=8`: "aaabbaba" -> "aaabbabaa" (or the mirror)
- `L=9`: "aaaabbbaba" -> "aaaabbbabaa" (or the mirror)

All futher `L` can be solved just by prefixing an additional `a` to the starting string.

Comment: Yes! This seems to be the pattern, I can't believe I didn't think of this :P

Comment: Yes, one seems to start losing hope after trying out the first few characters :D